# Type.GetTypeFromProgID() not working in class library

Tags: c#, .net

For context, I am working with this tutorial: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-bb141db3

My goal is to create a COM interface for a .NET 4.5 DLL in order to use the functionality in a .NET 2.0 context. My VS 2013 solution consists of the .NET 4.5 project with the desired functionality, an adapter project and the .NET 2.0 project.

The relevant code:

```
Type myClassAdapterType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Net4ToNet2Adapter.MyClassAdapter");
object myClassAdapterInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassAdapterType);
IMyClassAdapter myClassAdapter = (IMyClassAdapter)myClassAdapterInstance;
myClassAdapter.DoNet4Action();
```

This works when the .NET 2.0 project is configured as a console application but breaks when configured to output a class library. The  problem appears to be that `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` returns null in the case of the class library.

A manifest file is being used in the .NET 2.0 project in order to specify the dependancy on `Net4ToNet2Adapter` and my suspicion is that the class library configuration is not handling this correctly. I have tried using MT.EXE to manually embed the manifest with no success.

What is causing this code to fail when used as a DLL?

Comment: That's correct, a manifest only has an affect when it is Windows that loads the executable file.  Works fine on an EXE since it is the OS that loads it.  Not on a DLL, the OS is not involved since it the CLR that loads it.  You'll have to move the relevant manifest entries into the EXE project's manifest.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, that clarifies things a bit. However, in the end I will not have an EXE project only DLLs since the application loading this library is third party and not modifiable. Is there a way to get the CLR to load a dependency like Windows does for the EXE?

Comment: If you can't tinker with the client app then using a regfree manifest is never the correct solution.  You'll have to register it with Regasm.exe, only way.